# Setting image source cause Memory Leak (wpf, c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, memory-leaks

I'm creating a photobooth application.
It works fine, but when you are using it for a while, the program starts to slow down. I found a problem with the used memory.

#### Scenario:

In some point, a page is created and It creates a BitMap and draws a composition of images and a hovered template.
That image needs to be shown in the program, so I convert the Bitmap into a BitmapSource to set the Controls.Image.Source

#### Code:

```cs
Bitmap bi = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bi);

[paint some stuff here]

BitmapSource bs = ImageUtils.SourceFromBitmap(bi);
canvas.Source = bs; //PROBLEM HERE

[Dispose g and bi]
```

To clarify, the used methods here:

```
public static BitmapSource SourceFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    var hbm = bmp.GetHbitmap();
    try
    {
        BitmapSource result = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbm, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        return result;
    }
    finally { DeleteObject(hbm);}
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

#### Problem

The first test I did was comment the line *canvas.Source = bs;* where canvas is the name of the System.Windows.Controls.Image

If I do that, the use of memory doesn't grow.

#### Tried

I looked for some information and most of the cases it are related to BitmapImage, but I don't use it.

I've tried using the freeze method with the *BitmapSouce bs*, after and before setting it as the source, but the result is the same.

```
 BitmapSource bs = ImageUtils.SourceFromBitmap(bi);
 bs.Freeze();
 canvas.Source = bs;
```

```
 BitmapSource bs = ImageUtils.SourceFromBitmap(bi);
 canvas.Source = bs;
 bs.Freeze();
```

I also tried using the GC.Collect() just before the canvas.source reassignment, but the result is the same.

I tried to use the GC.Collect() after closing the page, but the result is the same.

The only way to solve the memory leak is by commenting the line, but it is not a solution...

#### Help:

What can I do?

Comment: for the garbage collector to collect it there needs to be NO reference to the object at all. When using names in your XAML you create a permanent reference to your xaml element.

Comment: @DenisSchaf Thanks for your comment. I've tried to change the Image element and create it programmatically instead of in the XAML. And set to null before closing the Page, but the result is the same, the memory keeps growing...

Comment: Naming an image canvas is highly confusing i dont recommend that... try setting the source directly without creating a copy in the bs variable. Not sure but eventually setting the source to bs creates a copy the it never disposed. First try removing the bs variable and if that doesn’t help try if disposing bs helps and report back what happened

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I tried like you said canvas.Source = ImageUtils.SourceFromBitmap(bi); But the result is the same. I'll keep trying more things.

Comment: Ok. I've Solved the problem. I'm not really happy with the result and I want to study more the scenario but... What did I do? Every time I need the page to show the image, I create the Page, this is an error, so now I reuse always the same page to solve the problem. I created a little project to show the problem and the solution. I'll answer myself showing the project. Right now I don't have time for it, but It will come soon.

Comment: you do not have to reuse the page if you dispose it. If the entire page is disposed correctly there wil not be any reference to it and the GC can do its job of cleaning it out.
Could you explain why you decided at some point that it makes sense to create a ne page?
keep in mind that a page in a frame will mostlikly always be accessible through the navigation services. I m not even 100% certain you can dispose elements that are part of your navigation history

Comment: Hi @DenisSchaf . This is my first c# project. So probably most of my decisions aren't the most efficient one. Creating the simple project I saw that it has no sense to create a new Page every time to show the same elements just with a different image. I think that the navigation thing that you are saying make sense, maybe that's why that image is never disposed...

Comment: Keep going! C# with WPF is a wonderful combination for programming desktop applications! By the way for the future consider adding more of you program-structure /code to you question. If we knew from the beginning what you were doing the community could have helped a lot quicker!

Comment: @FrancescMP, I've noticed the same memory leak. It seems that assigning a BitmapSource object to an XAML Image's Source Dependency Property causes a memory leak. I even call Dispose() on the System.Drawing.Bitmap passed to Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap() method. Have you had any luck squashing the leak yet?

Comment: And, of course, I do call Dispose() on the Window when the Window control that contains the Image is closed.